# How to run .net core application with launch profile via docker

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using Docker to deploy my ASP.NET Core app to a Linux machine. 
I have a pretty much default Dockerfile that looks like this:

```sh
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

So my point is to be able to build & run different instances of a project with different settings and different launch profiles declared in `launchsettings.json`. For that I need to use different dockerfiles but there is a question: **How do I setup a launch profile?**

Docker uses `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]` to launch the app (which seems to be the right thing to do). This string  means `dotnet` command will be executed and according to [doumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet?tabs=netcore21) seems that there's no way to pass launch profile as argument.

Yes, I know that `dotnet run` command allows to pass it via `--launch-profile <NAME>`. But [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run?tabs=netcore21) say it's not recommended to use just `dotnet run` and suggest to publish the app the way it's done in the Dockerfile

What is the right thing to do here?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a better question is: what is it you want from launchsettings? You can either use environment variables, or put the values you want in the `appsettings` and control them per environment, using the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` env variable.

Answer (score -1):

One possible way is to explicitly set all the different environment variables that the launchSettings includes in the `Dockerfile`. Do you have things other than `environmentVariables` in the `launchSettings.json`?

Comment: Yes, I also have different `applicationUrl`

Comment: You can also set that via environment variables in your Dockerfile